# Get character limit for long text area using Apex

Tags: apex, limits, describesobject, long-text-area

I am trying to get the character limit for a long text area. So for example I have a custom field called --> My_Text_area__c which has the char limit set as 5000.

So how can I get this value in my apex code. I am using this code to get all the long text area fields -->

```
Schema.SObjectField field = MapofField.get(fieldName);
Schema.DescribeFieldResult F = field.getDescribe();
if(F.getType() == Schema.DisplayType.TextArea && !field.getDescribe().isFilterable()){
    // get value here and do some logic
}
```

Comment: Have you checked `getLength()` method of `Schema.DescribeFieldResult`?

Comment: @metasync - that is the answer and should be posted as such

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`getLength()` method of `Schema.DescribeFieldResult` returns the length.

For ex.,

```
Schema.DescribeFieldResult field = Account.Description.getDescribe();
System.debug(field.getLength());
```

prints

```
32000
```